# Logitech unifying receiver worked briefly, now isn't detected. Help?

Tags: usb, mouse, logitech

18.04.1 LTS. New unifying receiver purchased. Initially didn't work, then miraculously started working briefly with Sonaar (unrelated to anything I did!) - paired mouse successfully. Then it stopped, in the middle of a session.

Neither Sonaar or ltunify see the receiver, and lsusb doesn't report anything Logitech related. I've tried all available USB ports, and have tried restarting and updating system. Next steps?

Comment: If `Bus 001 Device 004: ID 046d:c52b Logitech, Inc. Unifying Receiver` not seen is lsusb, more likely a hardware issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can try attaching the Unifying receiver to another laptop (Linux/Windows will work, but I didn't try with OSX). Pair them on the second computer. This will cause it to reset and allow your ubuntu to set/pair them once again once yu connect them back.